# How to create an email template from a responsive website?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a responsive daily deals website, and I wonder if I can simply copy paste the current HTML/CSS code to create an email template.

Here is a deal page. How do I turn this into an email template?
http://va.lezizfirsat.com/deals/2014/04/07/tea-at-gulens-palace-66-off/21/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to just copy + paste this code into an email and have it work, HTML emails are a particularly tedious part of development with a lot of specific best practices and email client considerations. I'd suggest checking out a [mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com/) template and altering it to fit into your brand style.